# Copy list item to another subsite list with powershell in SharePoint 2013

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I tried to copy the list from root to subsite using PowerShell like the code below, but when in execute there is an error like the picture below. what is missing from my code

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy "Unrestricted" -Force
$site= new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://Sharepointroot")
$web = $site.Openweb()
$listroot = $web.Lists["Meeting Room Book"]
$itemsroot = $listroot.items
$siteapps = Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://sharepointroot/Apps"
$listapps = $siteapps.Lists["Meeting Room History"]
$i = 0
foreach ($item in $itemsroot) {
   $i++
   write-host -foregroundcolor yellow $i
   $newitem= $listapps.Items.Add()
   $newitem["Title"] = $item["Title"]
   $newitem["Booking_x0020_Date"] = $item["Booking_x0020_Date"]
   $newitem["End_x0020_Time"] = $item["End_x0020_Time"]
   $newitem["Booked_x0020_By"] = $item["Booked_x0020_By"]
   $newitem["Display"] = $item["Display"]
   $newitem["Category"] = $item["Category"]
   $newitem["Status"] = $item["Status"]
   $newitem["Recurrence"] = $item["Recurrence"]
   $newitem["Meeting_x0020_Title"] = $item["Meeting_x0020_Title"]
   $newitem["BB"] = $item["BB"]
   $newitem.update()
}
$web.dispose
$site.dispose
start-sleep 10
```

and I have error like below.

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
at line:5 char:1
+ $newitem= $listapps.Items.Add()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [],RuntimeException
+FullyUalifiedErrorID  : NullArray
```

**Edit:**
for this case closed because of an error in me, the name of the list that is made is not the same. thank you for responding to my question.

for code copy list to another subsite its work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my understanding, this error means the script is attempting to do something, but another part of the script does not have any information to permit the first part of the script to work properly. In this case, $TargetItem .

Comment: where have you declare the $TargetItem?

Comment: sorry i wrote wrong, maybe $newitem no  $TargetItem. i will edit error..